# Mixing html5 <script async> with non-async <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html

After doing some interesting reading on async, I couldn't find any information on what's supposed to happen if you first have a regular script tag, followed by one with async.

I tried a quick test and it seems to do what I would hope: if I put a non-async tag first, it seems to always load it before the later async attributed tag. Here's the code I'm testing with:

test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
alert(window.jQuery);
```

In every case it seems that jQuery is loaded. Maybe I'm missing something in my tests. Is this correct? Can I put dependencies in non-async tags and then the dependents using async? Is it particularly beneficial to do this?

Are there any gotchas? What would happen if you had some asyncs and then a non-async? Would the async'd js load first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-async script tags block processing of the page. The browser may look ahead and load test.js before jquery has been executed, but the browser can not process the script as it does not know what jquery does to the page (document.writeln, changing the window object..).

So, yes it will work.

Doing this will make loading the page a bit faster, as one of the two script can be loaded asynchronously. It will probably not match the startup time of an optimizing, asynchronous loader though.

Answer (score 2):

Here the questions I can answer. I'm not 100% sure its a long time ago.

1. That first script is sync loaded. That means that it will wiat until that file is fully loaded and after that it proceeds to the next line.
2. Depends on when you need this file to be loaded. If it has to be loaded before the page is loaded, then you shouldn't use async for that file.
3. The asyncs will load simultaneously with the one non-async. If you have two non-asyncs at the end. That two non-asyncs will load sync. (DUH)
4. The async will load when it is on that line.

By it I mean the reader